# store Windows PowerShell output as a table in Azure SQL DB

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

I use the below Windows PowerShell script to extract all members of particular Yammer group and store the output as .csv file on my local machine.

What I need is to save this output as a table in Azure SQL DB. What would be the right way to approach this:

1. Amend the below script to save data in Azure Table?
2. Use some Azure SQL functionality?
3. Anything else?
   I would appreciate your help,

---

```
$GroupId=xxxxx

$Token = "xxxx"

$Headers = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer "+$Token }
  
$GroupCycle = 1
DO
    {
        $GetMoreGroupsUri = "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/in_group/$GroupId.xml?page=$GroupCycle"
        write-host ("REST API CALL : $GetMoreGroupsUri")
        [xml]$Xml = ((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $GetMoreGroupsUri -Method Get -Headers $Headers).content)
        $YammerGroups += $Xml.response.users.user
        $GroupCycle ++
        $GroupCount += $Xml.response.users.user.count
        write-host ("GROUPMEMBER COUNT : $GroupCount")
    }   
    While ($Xml.response.users.user.count -gt 0)
     $YammerGroups | Where {$_} | Export-Csv "$GroupId.csv" -Delimiter ","
```

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this problem slightly differently. I would use Azure to store the value of the variables I needed and keep the script somewhere else that is cloud accessible, Sharepoint comes to mind, so does GIT.

Here is the documentation on the Azure DB PowerShell Module AzTable:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell

Here are a couple of highlights:

```
#Install Module
Install-Module AzTable

#Get Table Contents
Get-AzStorageTable –Context $ctx | select Name
```

The Module is very well defined. I encourage you to take a look at all of the different calls listed in the Microsoft Doc.

Here is a breakdown:

1. Use Sharepoint or Git to store your script
2. If you want to store values, Azure DB is great. Use the PowerShell Module AzTable to interact with it. You can write and read tables as you see fit.
3. If you need dynamic variables, simply adjust the code to read the table value and variablize it. Should be easy to accomplish in some of the loops.